# HTML dom parser get inner h5 data

Tags: php

```
<div class="username-info-area">
                <img src="https://image5.sahibinden.com/users/47/06/46/p200_profile_14470646_8126809.png" class="user-profile-photo" height="50" width="50" alt="">
                <h5>familya yapı Gayrimenkul Gyo ltd şti</h5>
                </div>
```

I want to get h5 data.
I can access div.username-info-area.

```
$items = $new_data->find('div.username-info-area', 0)->outertext; 
        echo $items . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run an `if` clause inside of your `foreach` loop, check this example out for instance:

The script below will make sure that if there's an `h5` value it will print `$div` and its `outertext`.

```
<?php
foreach ($new_data->find('div[class=username-info-area]') as $div)
{
    if($div->find('h5') !== '')
    {
        print_r($div->outertext);
    }
}
?>
```

Or you can run another `foreach` loop inside of the next foreach loop, for example.

```
    <?php
foreach ($new_data->find('div[class=username-info-area]') as $div)
{
    foreach($div->find('h5') as $h5)
    {
        print_r($h5->outertext);
    }
}
?>
```

I hope this help.